# For any ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset V$, the inclusion $k! \cdot \mathfrak{m} \subset \sum_{x \in \mathfrak{m}} Vx^k$ holds

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 2.1.7. in Gabber, Ramero: Almost Ring Theory.

Let $V$ be a commutative ring with 1 and $\mathfrak{m} \in V$ an ideal.
Edit: $\mathfrak{m} / p \cdot \mathfrak{m}$ is generated (as a V-module) by the p-powers of its elements. (1)

One step in the proof is as follows:

The polarization identity $$k!\cdot x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot ... \cdot x_k = \sum_{I \in \{1,2,...,k\} } (-1)^{k-|I|} \cdot \left( \sum_{i \in I} x_i\right)^k$$ shows that if $N:=\sum_{x \in \mathfrak{m}} Vx^k$, then $k! \cdot \mathfrak{m} \subset N$

My idea was to set $x = x_1 \in \mathfrak{m}, x_2 = ... = x_k = 1$ and then hope that the RHS lands in $N$, or that at least the constant term and the $x$-coefficient are zero. While the former vanishes, the latter does not seem to vanish (if my calculation is correct).

Is there a simple way to see the claim without doing messy calculations?

EDIT:

Under the conditions I have given, this does not work:
Take $V = \mathbb{F}_q[T], q \neq p$ and $\mathfrak{m} = (T)$. Then $p \cdot \mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}$ and the assumption (1) holds trivially. Take $q$ large enough and $k < q$. Then $k! \cdot \mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}$ is clearly not contained in $N = (X^k)$.

So one really needs to assume that $\mathfrak{m}^2 = \mathfrak{m}$ as Darij Grinberg pointed out and then the claim is trivial.

Comment: Should your title be
"For any ideal ${\frak m}\subseteq V$, the inclusion $k!{\frak m}^k
\subseteq \sum_{x\in\frak m}Vx^k$ holds"?

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Comment: Then that is immediate from the polarisation identity.

Comment: Could you please add a bit of detail? I somehow cannot see it.

Comment: You haven't corrected the title. Anyway each element of $k!{\frak m}^k$ is a sum of elements $k!x_1\cdots x_k$ with the $x_i\in\frak m$.

Comment: Oh, I see: I corrected the $\in$ to $\subset$. But it still should be $\mathfrak{m}$ and not $\mathfrak{m}^k$. I will add more assumptions, maybe one needs to use them as well.

Comment: I'm upset that $V$ is not a vector space here...

Comment: As Gabber and Ramero point out in §2.1.1, they assume that $\mathfrak{m}^2 = \mathfrak{m}$. Does this assumption still stand in Proposition 2.1.7?

Comment: Thanks, one really needs to assume this. I was confused as one is proving the following claim: If $\mathfrak{m} \otimes_V \mathfrak{m}$ is flat, then $\mathfrak{m}^2 = \mathfrak{m}$ and for all $k>1$, the k-power elements of $\mathfrak{m}$ generate $\mathfrak{m}$. I have edited the original post.

Comment: Glad you were able to clear this up. IMHO you should probably report it to Ramero, as it *is* confusing.